# Using username 'newuser'. Server refused our key - What might I be missing?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

My root user can login using ssh but for some reason my newuser can't login using the same key.  I'm using putty and these are the messages I got.

Console message: `Using username 'newuser'. Server refused our key`

Putty Message: `Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)`

On my server I created a key file here `/home/newuser/.ssh/authorized_keys` and I pasted my SSH key into that file.  In addition I've browsed on my windows machine and attached the file in putty.

I'm pulling my hair out.  I'm not quite sure where to look to find the problem.  Is there something obvious I might be missing?

**---- update ----**

I logged into my root account and attempted to switch to newuser by typing `ssh newuser@my.ip.address` and no luck.  I got this message, `Permission denied (publickey).`

Comment: What does `/var/log/auth.log` say?

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks so much I checked the `auth.log` but it is huge.  What should I look for?

Comment: `tail -f` the `auth.log`, then attempt to connect again. See what new lines pop up.

Comment: Cool! Being a noob I haven't used `tail -f` before.  I looked in the log but didn't necessarily see anything.  However I did find my error.  root owned authorized_keys.  When I used `chmod` to assign ownership to newuser it fixed the problem on the spot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

`authorized_keys` was owned by root because that is the user that created it.  I used `chown` to switch ownership to newuser and it fixed the problem on the spot.